# code-like strings with background color, and using tabular environment

Tags: listings, tabularx, backgrounds

I am going to create the following code-like strings with latex, with same background (gray), font, etc. How can I do this?

[image]

I used `listings` package but inside

```
\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}
```

I couldn't use tabular environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Instead of using `listings`, just use `tabluar` with `ttfamily` (typewriter) font.

Answer (score 4):

If you have to type everything, can use a `tabular` with typewriter (`\ttfamily`) font.
In next code I've used [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/Pkg/tcolorbox) to provided a colored boxed background.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[fontupper=\small\ttfamily, colback=gray!10, arc=0pt]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
byte\#  & hexadecimal & text or \\
(hex)   &                 &  value      &  Meaning\\
0:      &  47 49 46 \\
       & 37 39 61 &    GIF89a   &   Header\\
 &&&                                Logical Screen Descriptor\\
6: &    03 00 &       3   &         - logical screen width in pixels\\
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]